# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in... error

Tags: php

I have a problem on this line `'href' => 'index.php?action=profile&user='.escape($user->data()->username).'',`

When the user is logged out, i get that error, but when i login, i dont get the error.

```
function toolbar_section()
{
    $user = new User();
    global $variables;
    $variables['menu_buttons'] = array(
        'home' => array(
            'title' => 'Pocetna',
            'href' => 'index.php',
            'show' => true,
        ),
        'profile' => array(
            'title' => 'Profil',
            'href' => 'index.php?action=profile&user='.escape($user->data()->username).'',
            'logged' => true,
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'title' => 'Odjava',
            'href' => 'index.php?action=logout',
            'logged' => true,
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: What is output of `var_dump($user);` ?

Comment: Where did you get that?

Comment: Does your user object contain an username while the user is logged out?
I'm assuming no, and the error is because the data you are trying to print doesn't actually exist?

Comment: Thats right. When the user is logged in, all is ok, but when i he logout...the code is still loading `escape($user->data()->username)` since its only showing for logged users.

Answer (score 1):

You have To check Condition before like

Code:

```
function toolbar_section()
{
    $user = new User();
    global $variables;
    if(count($user) > 0)
    {
       $href =  'index.php?action=profile&user='.escape($user->data()->username).'';
    }
    else
    {
       $href = 'index.php?action=profile&user='.escape("abc").'';
    }
    $variables['menu_buttons'] = array(
        'home' => array(
            'title' => 'Pocetna',
            'href' => 'index.php',
            'show' => true,
        ),
        'profile' => array(
            'title' => 'Profil',
            'href' => $href,
            'logged' => true,
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'title' => 'Odjava',
            'href' => 'index.php?action=logout',
            'logged' => true,
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Now i get `Notice: Undefined variable: href in...`

Comment: Ok try this condition in if statement if($user->data()->username != "" )

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!'` on that line

Comment: dont give space between !=  if($user->data()->username != "" )

Comment: Yeah right...but now i get the first error on line `$href =  'index.php?action=profile&user='.escape($user->data()->username).'';`

Comment: write print_r($user);die; before if condition and what output generate provide me

Comment: `User Object ( [_db:User:private] => DB Object ( [_pdo:DB:private] => PDO Object ( ) [_query:DB:private] => [_error:DB:private] => [_results:DB:private] => [_count:DB:private] => 0 ) [_data:User:private] => [_sessionName:User:private] => user [_cookieName:User:private] => hash [isLoggedIn:User:private] => )`

Comment: I found a solution. I put `if(Input::exists())` instead of your `if` and now everything works fine. Can you just explain me what does this mean `escape("abc")` because you wrote it.